# Can't get result from `az consumption` command

Tags: azure, az

I am using below command to get some properties (e.g `meterId`) of a newly created resource.

`az consumption usage list --include-meter-details 
--query "[?contains(instanceName,'<resource name>')].meterId" -o json`

But i am getting empty array `[]` as output. I could query for other resources and get their properties. It's happening only for newly created resources.

Is there any timeframe i need to wait before i can get them through consumption cli ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "[The consumption API data] is in the form of usage detail records
>   which are currently emitted once per meter per resource per day"

[Taken from Microsoft Docs for the Consumption API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-consumption-api-overview#usage-details-api)

So at most it should take, at most, 24 hours for the data to appear but depending on when Microsoft emit this data it could be a lesser amount of time.